# Is sending out automatic notification via SharePoint possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is sending out automatic notification via SharePoint possible? How can I do it? Do you have tutorial links or etc.

Comment: Do you have any specific conditions when you want to send the notification?

Comment: Please provide more information about your requirements??

Answer (score 2):

Below are the possible ways to send automatic notifications from SharePoint list/libraries:

1. **Alerts**- SharePoint OOTB Solution:

SharePoint alerts are email notifications that are sent by SharePoint when something changes in a library or list.

Check the steps for alerts configuration: [How to create SharePoint alerts](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/).

2. **SharePoint Designer Workflows**.

[Creating a workflow by using SharePoint Designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo).

3. **Microsoft Flow/Power Automate** - As you are using SharePoint Online

[Create a flow for a list or library in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-flow-for-a-list-or-library-in-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business-a9c3e03b-0654-46af-a254-20252e580d01).

You can use any one of the above solution for sending notifications from SharePoint. It totally depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Some Additional information:

1. Alert is the easiest approach to take. No need to learn much to configure. You can create one very quickly. However that also means you cannot customize it with your requirements. Triggers are quite limited and no additional information can be sent like user comments. It only notifies you with an E-mail there is a file/item is created/modified/deleted, and that is all.
2. As You are using SharePoint Online, MS Flow/Power Automate will be good choice. It is quite straightforward and is well integrated with other products in O365. And there are many pre-built templates available for you to choose. Tutorial about a sample flow:
   [Send an email when a new item is created or modified in a SharePoint list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/flow/get-started/create-your%20first-flow)

A flow Template you can try:[Notify me when a new file is added in SharePoint Online](https://asia.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/8af67cf007ee11e7a64d3bb26b42c7f5/notify-me-when-a-new-file-is-added-in-sharepoint-online/)